# how to ssh into a vagrant box when working with multi-vagrant environments?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have two vagrant boxes (wordpress VVV and laravel homestead) running at the moment at the same time. I always ssh to the machine with putty 127.0.1.1:2222 if I run vagrant homestead first I can only ssh this one machine at once. If I halt this machine by running vagrant halt and when trying to ssh to 127.0.0.1 I get "connection refused". How I can halt one machine and when straight away ssh to the other running vagrant box instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can ssh into multiple running vagrant machines at the same time if you know the port mappings between the guests and host. There's really no point in halting one machine in order to just ssh into another one.

Edit the Vagrantfiles of each vagrant environment, and add the following line:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: <PORT_NUMBER>, id: "ssh"
```

Where `<PORT_NUMBER`> must be replaced by a port available on your host machine.